# How can I push or replace page inside a Navigator Onsen UI?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

i am developing an app with cordova + Onsen UI.
I would like to know how can I use the .popPage() method to a navigator content.
Is it possible? I read and read and read but did not understood exactly the mean for a navigator.
I tried to get all this content off from navigator and put into a new page, then I defined the main page to this new I've created. But had no success too.
Look the code:

```
<ons-template id="home.html" style="background:#fff;">
  <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" title="Navigator">

      <ons-page id="content-home" class="fill">
        <div class="gradient">
```

So how can I use push or replace function for a page inside the navigator?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to manage the navigation, I'll show you an example with an `ons-button` element which, when triggered, pushes a new page into the navigator:

```
<ons-button modifier="light" ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('page1.html', { animation : 'slide' } )">
  Push Page
</ons-button>
```

You can find a full list of `ons-navigator` methods in the [official documentation](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html).

You also need to distinguish 3 concepts:

- **Push page**: adds a new page into the stack.
- **Pop page**: returns to the previous page on the stack, cannot be triggered if a push page action has not occurred yet.
- **Replace page**: replace the current page with the specified one.

You can see a full example of navigation by taking a look at [this CodePen example](http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/yrhtv)

**EDIT** (answers the opener's below comment)

I suggest you to don't put a page inside the navigator element but, instead, use the `page` attribute, which specifies the mail loaded page. Doing this, you can push the same page as many times as you wish.

[Here](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/PPKRRo) is a very simple example, with its code:

```
<ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="page1.html"></ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="page1.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-button ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('page1.html');">Push</ons-button>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Comment: Hi Andi, Sorry I was reading again my question and I think I was not so objective as I can. I know the ways to push page. The problem is that I want to use method .pushPage() to get a page that is INSIDE a <ons-navigator> and It is getting error. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: @harleydavi I just edited my answer adding the solution for your problem, if it helped you please consider to upvote the post and to mark as best answer :)

Comment: Thanks bro. Thats great.